# sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar is not valid for aggregation "dependents" of Element sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView

Tags: xml, user-interface, frontend, sapui5, sap-fiori

I can't put sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar inside sap.ui.core.FragmentDefinition

Let it be like this

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" >
    <fb:FilterBar >
        <fb:filterGroupItems>
            <fb:FilterGroupItem >
                <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox                                                                        
                    >
                    </MultiComboBox>
                </fb:control>
            </fb:FilterGroupItem>
            <fb:FilterGroupItem >
                <fb:control>
                    <Input                       
                    />
                </fb:control>
            </fb:FilterGroupItem>
            <fb:FilterGroupItem >
                <fb:control>
                    <Input                                                 
                    />
                </fb:control>
            </fb:FilterGroupItem>
        </fb:filterGroupItems>
    </fb:FilterBar>
    
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Someone who faced the same issue please let me know the reason)

Searching an answer in the internet didn't help me(